# Primefaces DataTable show/hide columns with selectMenuCheckbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces (3.5) datatable whose columns I want to show/hide using selectMenuCheckbox (sMCB) - each column is listed in the sMCb. The sMCb has a managed bean storing its values and the table columns have their render fields set to a method that looks to see if the column is checked or not in the checkbox.

The sMCb has an "onChange" parameter in which I am using a basic javascript call "tableName.update()" to tell it to update. 1) It doesn't work, and 2) I am not sure if its the right way to get the table to re-render or if I should be doing something else.

Can someone suggest a way to do this, with a datatable, selectMenuCheckbox, and having the column show/hide when each checkbox is changed.

I have worked with JSF/Primefaces before, but am really new to javascript/jquery/etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Could the given answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you say, the selectMenuCheckBoxes work server-side, so does the `render` attribute. A pure client-side javascript approach will imo not work.

To get the columns updated, I would expect something like re-rendering the table in case a checkbox was clicked.

Without knowing your direct xhtml (and personally coming from the richfaces front), the checkbox might look something like (untested)

```
<h:selectMenuCheckBox value="#{managedBean.firstColumnChecked}">
    <f:ajax event="change" render="yourDataTableIdHere" />
</h:selectMenuCheckBox>
```

Hope it helps...